# SSL certificate conditional check using chef

Tags: ruby, ssl, iis, chef-infra

I am working on a chef code that imports the certificate to the personal store using the pfx file, and add the https binding in the IIS and add the ssl certificate. I am successful with the code, and the code looks like below.

However i would like to put a conditional check before i run these steps, i.e if the ssl certificate is already available on the https binding on  IIS, i do not want to run any of the below script.

Could you help me with that first line of 'IF' statement on how to see if the SSL is already installed?

```
# Import certificates to local machine personal store
windows_certificate 'cert.pfx' do  
    pfx_password    '@password'  
end

#Setup a HTTPS port on IIS
iis_site 'Default Web Site' do  
  action :config  
  bindings 'http/*:80:,https/*:443:'  
end

#Add the certificate to the IIS 
windows_certificate_binding 'ssl certificate name' do  
  address '0.0.0.0'  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use notifications:

```
# Import certificates to local machine personal store
windows_certificate 'cert.pfx' do  
    pfx_password    '@password'
    notifies :config, 'iis_site[Default Web Site]'
end

#Setup a HTTPS port on IIS
iis_site 'Default Web Site' do  
  action :nothing  
  bindings 'http/*:80:,https/*:443:'  
end
```

Or something like that. Every resource will send out the configured notification actions if and only if it is "updated" (where updated means different things for different resources).